# Spring Boot OAuth doesn't return a refresh token for clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an API that I've developed in Spring Boot, and I've just noticed that it's not returning a refresh token when you request an access token.

The response from the API looks like this;

```
{
    "access_token": "ed0bdc62-dccf-4f58-933c-e28ad9598843",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 2589494,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

My configuration looks like this;

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "myapi";

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources
                    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/**", "/view/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource);
        }
    }

}
```

I previously had the project setup to use JWT for access tokens and that did return a refresh token, however I had to remove JWT as it wasn't compatible with using the token store.

To confirm, it returns a refresh token when the grant_type = password, but not when it's set to 'client_credentials'.

Does anyone have any suggestions why my configuration doesn't return a refresh token?

Answer (score 5):

[4.3.3. Access Token Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) (The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework) says *"A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included."* Therefore, most implementations of OAuth 2.0 authorization servers do not generate a refresh token in [Client Credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4).

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue, then I changed in this method, I added REFRESH_TOKEN then in the response I am getting refresh_token value.

static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
            configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(messageDigestPasswordEncoder.encode(CLIENT_SECRET))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE,REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE ,TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
                 refreshTokenValiditySeconds(REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
 }
```