# How to get refresh token with grant type client_credentials

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring-boot 2.5.0 for a REST API and implemented OAuth using following classes. I am aware that in grant type 'client_credentials' refresh token is not returned. However, the android team I am working with is adamant about having refresh token in grant type 'client_credentials' .
So I am seeking a way to get refresh tokens in client_credential

Currently , as per the default, I am only getting refresh_token in grant_type password.

The classes I am using :

1) AuthorizationServerConfiguration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        int accessTokenMinutesValidity = 60;
        int refreshTokenMinutesValidity = 24 * 60;
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("{noop}secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * accessTokenMinutesValidity ).//Access token is only valid for 60 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60 * refreshTokenMinutesValidity);//Refresh token is only valid for 24 hours
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
            .realm(REALM+"/client");
    }

}
```

2) MethodSecurityConfig

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

3) OAuth2SecurityConfiguration

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource customDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("<connection string>");
        dataSource.setUsername("<username>");
        dataSource.setPassword("<password>");

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource ds() {
        //return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return customDataSource();
    }

    //USERS FROM DATABASE
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        BCryptPasswordEncoder enc;

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select USERNAME, ENC_PASSWD as PASSWORD, IS_ACTIVE AS ENABLED FROM USER_MSTR WHERE USERNAME=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select USERNAME, 'ROLE_CLIENT' as ROLE from USER_MSTR where USERNAME=?")
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        ;

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

4) ResourceServerConfiguration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/category_mstr/**", "/equipment/**", "/param_mstr/**", "/chklist_txn/**", "/settings/**", "/user/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/category_mstr/**", "/equipment/**", "/param_mstr/**", "/chklist_txn/**", "/settings/**", "/user/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

currently with grant_type = password, I am getting response  as

```
{
    "access_token": "25ca1254-4460-44bd-94c3-367f4b21e3b0",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "ef64adad-3772-4e0c-ae30-50358cdfffe1",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read trust write"
}
```

and with grant_type = client_credentials, I am getting response as

```
{
    "access_token": "8c2bcdac-0a6b-4262-8664-75f1e0dc8351",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "read trust write"
}
```

How do I get response with refresh_token in above ??

I have tried extending ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider as follows

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider;

public class CCAccessTokenProvider extends ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsRefresh(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but I don't know where to fit it in my current architecture

--EDIT

I am seeking a solution to this critical issue and the other thread doesn't address it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot OAuth doesn't return a refresh token for clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262924/spring-boot-oauth-doesnt-return-a-refresh-token-for-clients)

Comment: @AmanGarg , that thread doesn't still doesn't answer my question. Hence I think its  not a duplicate. I am seeking a solution.

Comment: in which version of spring boot does it support then ?